# Xfce4 panel launcher – how to hide arrow for multi-launchers (gtk.css or gtkrc)

Tags: xubuntu, launcher, xfce, panel, xfce-panel

When I was using Xubuntu 14.04, some how I had a GTK theme that, when the ‘Arrow Button Position’ was set Inside Button, the arrow was completely hidden but now, with XFCE 4.14 and Xubuntu 19.10, a part of the arrow keeps visible and with 'show label instead of icon', gets really ugly.
As I’m working on a theme, I would like to find a css code so that the arrow gets completely hidden when set to Inside Button (‘arrow-position 5’ in xfconf).
xfce gtkrc-2 docs says that special widget names in the XfceLauncherPlugin are ‘launcher-button’ and ‘launcher-arrow’.

So, how to hide the arrow with something like this?

```
.xfce4-panel.panel button.launcher-arrow { width: 0px; height: 0px; }
```

Or maybe with gtkrc...

Thanks.

Comment: This  does the trick to hide the arrow
    `#launcher-arrow { color: transparent; }`
but opens another issue: it also affects the label color and with ‘show label instead of icon’ the label also becomes transparent or of any other color assigned in the snippet.

Comment: After `#launcher-arrow { color: transparent; }` adding `#launcher-arrow label { color: black; }` solves the problem, as reported in this thread from Xfce.org: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=56842#p56842